# values does not adds to array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, I want to add values to an array from two different functions, but the values are being added to the array only inside the first function. Please tell what can be the issue?

**Code:**

```
public $ChnCat_tags = array();
function first_function() {
    //some code 
    $ChnCat_tags[] = array(
        'level' => $level,
        'value' => $row_vct->id_vct,
        'label' => $row_vct->displayname_vct,
        'disable' => $disb
    );
    $recursion_result = second_function($ChnCat_tags);
    return $ChnCat_tags; //only returns values added inside first_function
}

function second_function($ChnCat_tags) {
    //some code
    $ChnCat_tags[] = array(
        'level' => $level,
        'value' => $row_vct->id_vct,
        'label' => $row_vct->displayname_vct,
        'disable' => $disb
    );
    recursion_result = second_function($ChnCat_tags);
    return recursion_result;
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile, re: `recursion_result`... so that's probably your main issue... how is this even running?

Comment: @Alex, see now.

Comment: it's still not completely fixed, but I get the idea.

Comment: @Alex, can you answer to it?

Comment: i'm a bit confused... in your second function you run itself again (inside itself) which will result in an endless loop. is this an error?

Comment: in actual code i have some base case that ends the recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could just start using `$this->ChnCat_tags` instead of just `ChnCat_tags` everywhere.

Or ([pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)):

```
function first_function() {
    //some code 
    $ChnCat_tags[] = array(
        'level' => $level,
        'value' => $row_vct->id_vct,
        'label' => $row_vct->displayname_vct,
        'disable' => $disb
    );
    second_function($ChnCat_tags);
    return $ChnCat_tags;
}

function second_function(&$ChnCat_tags) {
    //some code
    $ChnCat_tags[] = array(
        'level' => $level,
        'value' => $row_vct->id_vct,
        'label' => $row_vct->displayname_vct,
        'disable' => $disb
    );
    second_function($ChnCat_tags);
    // no need to return now
    //return recursion_result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
function first_function() {

    $ChnCat_tags[] = array(
        'level' => $level,
        'value' => $row_vct->id_vct,
        'label' => $row_vct->displayname_vct,
        'disable' => $disb
    );

    # Must call function with $this
    $recursion_result = $this->second_function($ChnCat_tags); 

    # print the value of $recursion_result whish hold entire data
    print_r($recursion_result); 
}

function second_function($ChnCat_tags) {

    $ChnCat_tags[] = array(
        'level' => $level,
        'value' => $row_vct->id_vct,
        'label' => $row_vct->displayname_vct,
        'disable' => $disb
    );
    # just return the array data.
    return $ChnCat_tags;
}
```